# Error: "No such option: -l" when running yt-dlp

Tags: video, ffmpeg, youtube-dl, yt-dlp

I have adapted code from [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260944/encode-video-for-ipod-classic) to try to download a video and use ffmpeg to alter it

```
yt-dlp    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtkqwslbLY8" -o  ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 -preset fast -profile:v baseline \
-level 3 -refs 6 -vf "scale=640:-1,pad=iw:480:0:(oh-ih)/2,format=yuv420p" \
-acodec copy output.mp4
```

However, when I run this I'm getting the error:

```
yt-dlp: error: no such option: -l
```

Any ideas of how to fix this?

Comment: **(1)** You didn't use `L` in your command so don't know how you got that error from the shown code. Is it possible you made an edit that you're not telling us about? **(2)** What happens if you try a video download only (no FFmpeg extra commands), does the video save correctly? Trying to see if your error is from YT-dl side or from FFmpeg side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yt-dlp "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtkqwslbLY8" -o - | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 -preset fast -profile:v baseline -level 3 -refs 6 -vf "scale=640:-1,pad=iw:480:0:(oh-ih)/2,format=yuv420p" -acodec copy output.mp4`

1. yt-dlp must write to STDOUT with `-o -` , not in a regular file
2. Then pipe to `ffmpeg`, not `-i in.mp4` but  `| ffmpeg -i -`
   This is a smart way to do that.

Comment: This works. Any suggestions for how to dynamically name the output after the name of the Youtube video? I can also make a separate SO post. Thanks

Comment: @garson a separate post will be more useful for everyone